Incrementing Indices of Variables through some kind of Operator
I have some function which contains variables $B_i$ and want a way to transform this function into the same operations of the variable but just with the indices shifted: $B_i \rightarrow B_{i+1}$ For example with this operator T:  $$f(i,n)=5B_2(n)B_0(n)^i + 4B_3(n)B_0(n)^{i-1}$$ $$T[f(i,n)] =5B_3(n)B_1(n)^i + 4B_4(n)B_1(n)^{i-1}$$ I'm wondering if this has some sort of notation around it and if it's been studied before, I'm working on a problem where this came up while discovering diagonal patterns within my formulas where the rows of some two-dimensional table can be mapped to the diagonals of that table. Any info on this or directions to point me in would be appreciated.

There are shift operators.

But it's not a computer program; I have thought of those, but it just doesn't seem right for what I'm doing. Maybe this is just some niche case that I have to deal with. I want to more intuitively understand this in a more abstract sense, like studying the properties of this transformation.

Shift operators.
